# Mixing code and attributes in TypeScript class

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a simple TypeScript class defined like this:

```
export class Piece {
    Qty: number;
    Weight: number;
    Type: string;

    totalWeight() {
        return Qty * Weight;
    }
}
```

And, I have an Angular 5 service that has a method like this:

```
  get(id: number) {
      return this.http.get<Piece>(myAPIURL + id);
  }
```

And my Angular code calls this as follows:

```
const myPiece: Piece;
this.myService.get(2).subscribe(data => myPiece = data);
```

When all is said and done, the variable 'myPiece' contains the correct data; however, there is no totalWeight() method attached to it. I think I understand why (because the server returned the data/attributes, but obviously no code). But is there a way to somehow unite the data and the code/methods again?

My background is with C# objects, and I'm still new to Java/TypeScript. I'm guessing this may have something to do with the prototypical inheritance in JavaScript?

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to actually instantiate the class from the http call. TypeScript is just javascript with type hinting, not actual casting can be done, because javascript doesn't have this. So to make something a certain class, you really have to instantiate this with the `new` keyword

```
get(id: number) {
  return this.http.get<Piece>(myAPIURL + id).pipe(
    map((data) => ({ ...new Piece(), ...data}))
  )
}
```

or

```
map((data) => Object.assign(new Piece(), data))
```

Whatever you find more legible

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! I'll give it a try and see how it goes.